# after compilation in Vim : cursor in gg

Tags: vimrc, terminal, cursor, filetype-markdown

I'm french... sorry for my english

I try to compile files (.tex, .md ... using vim). I open terminal and make the compilation ; just before the compilation i save the file and put a marker in the place i am. But, after the compilation, the cursor is on first line and not at the place where i put the marker.
I don't know how to do in order that the cursor is in the same place before and after the compilation. Can you help me ?
the line for compilation in my .vimrc (for markdown --> pdf for example) :

`` nnoremap \p mz:w<CR>:terminal<CR><C-w>J<C-w>24-file=$(ls -1t \| head -1)<CR>name=${file%.*}<CR>pandoc $name".md" -o $name".pdf" && exit 0<CR>`z ``

this line puts a marker (z) where i am in the file, opens a terminal, reduces it in the bottom of the screen, find the file, makes the compilation in order to have a pdf file, and then exit the terminal. Then, with  `` `z `` I would try to go to the place where I was before compilation but it doesn't work, the cursor is in "gg". I can go to the initial position with  `` `z `` manually but I would want to make it automatically in my vimrc.

I have tried with marker (as above) and also with functions getpos, setpos but also with winsaveview, winrestview, the result is the same : cursor in "gg".

it seems the fact to close terminal produces this issue. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Just for point of reference I don't see this behavior so it's not a general Vim issue. Focus should be on your particular setup. Have tried without a vimrc file and/or plugins? (run vim with `vim --clean`, for example) See [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ; I have tried with the link, but the result is the same : cursor always in gg after compilation. And nevertheless, I have no plugin installed.

Comment: My problem seems to be the one related here : https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5820

Comment: solved for me : it was due to the use of BufEnter in my vimrc.